# Need a fix in bash script

Tags: bash

I am having 180 sub directories where I need to copy `"hcc_mac_.db"` and need to write `"hcc_mac"` in `sub_block_db.txt` file.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
srcdir="/pr/disk_up/bpalla/mac_H.ssg0p65v0c.lib.gz_2090104230/hdm/hcc_mac_.db"
dicts=(dict1 dict2 dict3 ..... dict180)
var1="hcc_mac" 

for dict in "${dicts[@]}"
do
    dstdir="src/meta/tools/2in/les/$dict/."
    cp -rf $srcdir "$dstdir"
    cat > src/meta/tools/2in/les/"$dict"/sub_block_db.lst << EOF1
$var1 
EOF1
done
```

It is copying the .db to all 180 directories but not writing this "hcc_mac" in sub_block_db.txt file. Instead I am getting permission denied issue. But when I am doing manually I am not getting any issues.

Can anyone please help me to fix this .. please

Comment: I would first, for better reliability, use `cat >$dstdir/sub_block_db.lst <<EOF1`, and, for debugging the problem, place right before the `cat` command a `ls -ld $dstdir` and also a `ls -ld $dstdir/*.lst` and a `id -u -n`, just to verify the permissions.

Comment: Permissions are fine because when I am doing manually its working. But with script its not working.

Comment: Did you actually put in the checks into the script, as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
cat > src/meta/tools/2in/les/"$dict"/sub_block_db.lst << EOF1
$var1 
EOF1
```

did you try

```
echo $var1 > src/meta/tools/2in/les/"$dict"/sub_block_db.lst
```

Comment: I am still getting same issue. Permission denied.

Comment: do you run the script from a different directory?
how do you run the script?

Comment: from a different directory.

Comment: then try to do this manually from the same place as from where you run the script from. My guess is you will notice you have a path error somewhere.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot to add: I have made the painful experience that it is always a good idea to work with absolute paths. always. why? context.
With absolute paths, you can always be sure that whereever, whoever, whenver, the script is run, its always going to the right places.